# virtual method table from void pointer

Tags: c++

Given a void pointer that's pointing to a class, how would I access the virtual method table and the functions of that class without casting to that class?

```
class Thing{
    private:
        virtual int foo(){
            return 5;
        }

        virtual int bar(){
            return 4;
        }

    public:
        Thing(){
        }
}

Thing thing;
void *thing = &thing;
int getFoo(void* thing){
   //Code here to get virtual method table and call function

}
```

Comment: "how would I access the virtual method table and the functions of that class without casting to that class?" - you would not.

Comment: Why do you even want to access the virtual method table? I can't think of any reason you would need to do that

Comment: I would presume the location of the virtual pointer table is implementation-defined?

Comment: @tambre Whether the table exists at all  is implementation defined.

Comment: Formally, not implementation defined, although implementation specific. In the language definition, "implementation defined" means implementation specific **and** the implementation is required to document what it does.

Comment: Well, first, you would look at how the compiler constructs the class and how it implements the vtable(s), which is very much an implementation-specific thing (and for the latter part, might even be "it doesn't).  For some compilers (such as GCC), documentation is relatively easy to find; for ones that lack documentation of their internal workings (such as MSVC), you're likely going to need to either reverse-engineer it, or find code from someone else that already has.  Either way, your code will be very closely coupled to your chosen compiler.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, though.  Why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to make a C library for `Thing`, so it can be used in C programs?  Are you trying to use polymorphism without the language's built-in form of virtual dispatch?  Or is it something else altogether?

Comment: It's actually for an interview problem. The idea is that Thing has private variables and private virtual functions and I'm supposed to access them from outside the class. It's an interesting problem. I got the variables by simply accessing the pointer as an array and finding where those variables are stored in the class. I submitted an answer to getting the functions by just casting it to a version of the class where those functions are public but the company asked if I can solve it by accessing the virtual method table.

Comment: [this](https://kaisar-haque.blogspot.ca/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html) seems to be what I'm trying to do but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In portable C++ the only thing you can do is cast it back to the original type. (You can also add a const qualifier.)

Your compiler might document how the vtable, if it uses one, can be obtained from the pointer you have, and you could use that. But to emphasise, you have not written portable C++ if you take that route.

Work with the language, not against it.

Answer (score 0):

> how would I access the virtual method table and the functions of that class without casting to that class?

C++ does not provide such functionality. If you need that indeed you can use particular compiler/platform, research and put an ugly hack (using offset and the like). But you need to be aware that such "solution" could be not portable even within same compiler of different versions.

Comment: is the method described here possible: https://kaisar-haque.blogspot.ca/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html  ?

Comment: @H.DJEMAI it may work on a specific compiler, but it does not make it portable of course. An nobody guarantees that it will still work tomorrow even if it does today.